# Can someone make me understand how sortedArrayUsingFunction works?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray

my array has the following:

```
{
   "4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000" : {
     "_id" : {
       "$id" : "4eb57e72c7e24c014f000000"
     },
     "author" : "tim",
     "comments" : [],
     "created": {
       "sec" : 1320517234,
       "used" : 856000
     },
     "picture" : "http://someurl.com",
     "text" : "this is a test",
     "title" : "test",
     "type" : ["test"]
   }
```

I want to sort by created (sec value)

this is what I have....I just do not know how sortedArrayUsingFunction works. I mean what am I comparing in the compare function??

```
jokesArray = [unSortedContentArray sortedArrayUsingFunction:Sort_Created_Comparer context:self]; 

NSInteger Sort_Created_Comparer(id num1, id num2, void *context)
{
    int v1 = [num1 getSecFromJSONValue];
    int v2 = [num2 getSecFromJSONValue];
    if (v1 < v2)
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    else if (v1 > v2)
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    else
        return NSOrderedSame;
}
```

Comment: Just so we're clear, the code you currently have works properly, but you want to learn why?

Comment: @craig I do need help understanding it because I do not know what is being passed into Sort_Created_Comparer (num1, num2). Also how do I pull the sec value from the array. So yes I am kind of lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`num1` and `num2` are 2 elements of your array and context is an object that you can pass in to your function to help you with the sort.

Your function will be called many times on the array and the result of the sort will be returned to you in a new array.

Is that what you are wondering?

Comment: No worries @VinceBurn, just a bit of polish on an already good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function is called to compare two values at a time from your NSArray. This is how the sorting is done.

Answer (score 0):

The comparison function is your way of telling the sort algorithm how you want your objects ordered. Without it, it has no way of knowing what the final order should be.

In your example code the argument names `num1` and `num2` are very misleading. They would be more accurately named `object1` and `object2`. If `object1` should come before `object2` then return `NSOrderedAscending`. If it should come after then `NSOrderedDescending` otherwise return `NSOrderedSame`.

To illustrate, here is an example that sorts hypothetical `Person` objects by age (lowest to highest).

```
NSInteger youngest_first(id object1, id object2, void *context) {
    if (object1.age < object2.age) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (object1.age > object2.age) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

Notice that I didn't even use the context parameter as my objects themselves had sufficient information to determine the order.

If I instead want them to be sorted by descending height then I could pass the following:

```
NSInteger tallest_first(id object1, id object2, void *context) {
    if (object1.height > object2.height) {
        return NSOrderedAscending;
    }
    else if (object1.height < object2.height) {
        return NSOrderedDescending;
    }
    else {
        return NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

One thing that is **very important** is that your function should return a consistent result if the arguments are passed in the other order. For example if `tallest_first(adam, joe, NULL)` returns `NSOrderedDescending` then `tallest_first(joe, adam, NULL)` should return `NSOrderedAscending`. If not your comparison function contradicts itself.